# Why can't I specify a local path to a file I want to source in zsh?

Tags: shell, zsh

I am new to zsh and I just wanted to reload .zshrc after some modifications. I am in my home directory and when I type `. .zshrc` I get the following output `.: no such file or directory: .zshrc`. It appears that `. ~/.zshrc` works. Is there a way to be able to provide a local path to that kind of command ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `source` instead of `.` for that.

From `zshbuiltins(1)`:

> **source** file [ arg ... ]
>   Same  as `.', except that the current directory is always searched and is always searched first, before directories in $path.

Answer (score 1):

The current directory is not in your `PATH`, either provide a relative or absolute path to `.zshrc` or add `.` or `$HOME` at the end of your `PATH`. Beware having `.` in the `PATH` is not a recommended practice.